# Что такое GnomeShell?

Tags: gnome, linux

Осваиваю никсы с точки зрения пользователя - и встретился с такими определениями - Gnome и GnomeShell - обьясните в чем разница? Понимаю что Гном это нечто большее - тогда второе что означает?

Потом - [тут](http://www.opennet.ru/opennews/art.shtml?num=33616) - прочел про Cairo-Dock - и что оно аналог ГномоШелла - как вообще этот КайроДок вклинивается в концепцию ДЕ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GnomeShell - следующее поколение графической оболочки Gnome. Его появление вызвало неоднозначную реакцию в линуксобщественности. GS гораздо более требовательна к параметрам графических адаптеров, G же способен легко переносить старые адаптеры. Например последние версии дистрибутивов Ubuntu на борту имеют GUI Unity, однако привыкшие пользователи 10 версий (в том числе и я) пробовали перейти на альтернативный интерфейс GS... На мой взгляд альтернативным назвать его нельзя. Один из классических вариантов Gnome можно лицезреть на Mint. В общем смысле создание GS - это попытка продолжить славные времена Gnome и по мнению многих попытка неудачная.

Comment: тогда Кайро что это? и какое отношение оно имеет к Гному и - как сказано на ихнем сайте - к КДЕ?

Answer (score 1):

Кайро-док - это панель задач для нового гнома2. В гноме2 ее нет, типа так модно: "вот смотрите, я теперь выгляжу как айфон!", вот и приходится извращаться, ставить кайро-доки и т.п., часто недопиленные вещи. Я использую Panel-docklet - он больше всего похож на старую добрую панель задач